# get inner component from flexGlobals.topLevelApplication

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I feel the way inner components could be accessed be better than what I know.
I know we can access any inner component something like:
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.someChild1.someChild2.someChild3… and so on

I've a components which has number of parent components hierarchy. I wish to know if there could be anyway I could access the last child without referring all of its parent.

I need to trigger an event on that component.

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.child1.child2.child3.dispatchEvent(new Event('clearData', true));
```

Updated: I tried the way you suggested in point 1. I've added the event listener on child component and try to dispatch it from a action script file, but it went unheared.\

```
child3.addEventLisener('clearData', clearHandler);
```

And then I dispatched the event some thing like:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(modelApp.CLEAR_PALETTE, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I understood from the question used no good principles of application design, but that's another question. 
In your case, you can use stage as global currentTarget for bubbles events. Dispatch event from displayObject with bubbles = true; In target display object listen event with stage object with/out capture phase.

in any displayObject:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent", true));
```

in target displayObject:

```
// add ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener in constructor or when component creation complete
protected function component_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);
}

..

protected function onAddToStage(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener("myEvent", eventHandler, true);
}

protected function eventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("eventHandler");
}
```

It is better than use reference to FlexGlobals object. Code more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManger.addEventLisener('clearData', clearHandler);
```

in child3

and dispacthed it from any where you want,

for dispatching use the following

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.dispatchEvent(new Event(modelApp.CLEAR_PALETTE, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go down to the level of component and addEventListener on initialize.
and dispatch from where ever you want.

other way is to do that, you need to save component reference(ID) in object on creationComplete. save its refence in your model. now you can access it where ever you want. and do what ever you want.

i also did in this way, i saved my screen components refrence in an array and access it where i need to dynamically validate all components.

otherwise you need nested looping to got your required child.